# Svg masks / clipping path woes

Tags: html, css, svg

here is a fiddle to show my current working of svg:

http://jsfiddle.net/r3plica/g046qfyq/

As you can see, I have added two circles which are masking the content behind.
The mask is working as I want, but! I would like to change the background of the all of it to **rgba(0,0,0,0.5)**.

At the moment I added:

```
background-color: pink;
```

this is applied to the .mask class and has colored in the circles. What I want to do is colour in everything but the circles.

Here is an image explaining what I mean.

[image]

If anyone can help me with this, that would be super :)

**Update 1**

I am trying to create this:

[image]

I have this fiddle now:

http://jsfiddle.net/r3plica/g046qfyq/2/

If I could **invert** the clipping path, that would be the solution.
Is there anyway to do this?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your svg `clippath` to a `mask`, add a white rectangle to cover all your area and set the circles in black.

```
<mask id="myMask">
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="1000" height="1000" fill="white"/>
  <circle cx="30" cy="30" r="20" fill="Black"/>
  <circle cx="200" cy="200" r="100" fill="Black" />
</mask>
```

and use it with the `mask` css property.`

```
.mask {
  mask: url(#myMask); 
}
```

you can improve it a bit by placing both the mask and the content in a container with `position:relative` and then adding `position:absolute` to your `.modal` class.

Comment: that says ie is not supported at all, but in this fiddle, it works: http://jsfiddle.net/giri_jeedigunta/Z2J34/

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap everything with div and apply `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)` as background-color.
http://jsfiddle.net/Justinas_Jurciukonis/g046qfyq/3/

**EDIT**
Why not just use overlay with dark background color and css image of rectangle with hole inside of it? Than just use background-position to move that circle in page.

Comment: aye, but the reason I want to do it as transparent black is I want it to show the content underneath also.

Comment: @r3plica Check updated JSfiddle, do you want something like this?

Comment: nah, check my last fiddle. The last fiddle I did is exactly what I want in reverse. If it can be inverted or done another way, then that is perfect.