# css 3 and html 5 creating masks

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to create this using css 3?

[image]

As you can see, there is a transparent circle but the container has a black background with 50% opacity.

I thought it might be doable using svg but it doesn't look possible.

Comment: use mask and z-index for that cicle

Comment: Hasn't this already been asked - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25179137/svg-masks-clipping-path-woes

Comment: different question. I am asking here is there is a better way of doing it without using svg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `box-shadow` by setting the fourth argument as the shadow spread distance, just set it at an high number so you are certain you're covering the whole screen area.

```
.mask {
  position: fixed;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 99999px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.8);
}
```

This will generate a circle mask with 200px diameter, then you can position it on the screen using top/left wherever you like.

Here's a codepen if you want to see it in action http://codepen.io/luigimannoni/pen/cbpwL

Cheers

Comment: awesome, much better than using svg. Cheers! :)

Comment: a question. How would this work if I wanted 2 circles?

Comment: That would be a 500 point bounty question

Comment: But I am not that greedy, basically you dissect the overlay in small containers and apply `overflow: hidden` to each of those. A demo worths more than thousand words: http://codepen.io/luigimannoni/pen/CgdIA

Comment: Also, three masks: http://codepen.io/luigimannoni/pen/GLajx , four masks: http://codepen.io/luigimannoni/pen/Lntem ... You get the idea

Answer (score 0):

You can use the mask that overlays the whole content and use higher z-index value than the mask for the circle element.

Comment: would it be possible for you to give me an example?